# adding a value for X number of rows and then another value for the next x number of rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Here is an example of my database:

```
id    year   birthday      ...
1     1995   10 Oct 1990   ... 
1     1996   10 Oct 1990   ...
      1997   10 Oct 1990   ...
2     1995   01 Aug 1988   ...
2     1996   01 Aug 1988   ...
2     1997   01 Aug 1988   ...
3     1995   21 Mar 1987   ...
      1996   21 Mar 1987   ...
      1997   21 Mar 1987   ...
```

The id is a number identifying and individual.  The database is longitudinal therefore there are multiple collection dates, which I have called year.  I have had to compile this data from different databases containing the information so some of the id numbers are not entered but I want them to be.  For example, individual in this database is missing the id number for 1997 and the third individual is missing it for 1996 and 1997.  Is there a way to add these values by using a formula?  I have data of about 300 individuals over 13 years, so I don't want to enter them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen enough of you data but I think a macro would be more suitable

```
Sub FillInEmpties()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim cell As Range
    For i = 1 To lr
        Set cell = Range("A" & i)
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

because you would have to enter the formula in each of the empty cells which is not really an efficient way of doing things.

---

An alternative would be to compare the years and then fill in column A based on year difference

example

stick this in A3 and drag it down

```
=IF(B3>B2,A2,A2+1)
```

[image]

Comment: The only foreseeable problem with the formula above would be that not every individual is going to be older than the original, as in 1 isn't older than some of the other individuals within the database.  How would I be able to correct for that?

Comment: that's using a formula - use the macro instead then

Comment: I tried running that macro but there was some sort of error.  Are there parts of the macro that need to be changed?

Comment: @user2969279 couldn't tell you without knowing the *error type* or *message*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need to do this one-time or regularly, and this might belong on SuperUser but here's one code-free method:

1. Select Column A.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to bring up GoTo and then select **Blanks**.
   This will select the cells you wish to fill in.
3. In the formula bar, enter the cell above the first blank cell selected, for example below, the first blank cell is A4, so I entered `=A3`.

   [image: Spreadsheet image]
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the formula will be copied to the previously blank cells.
5. Copy-paste as values and you're done.